# Why is my ELSE Statment Is giving me a ERROR?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm Trying to Create a stored procedure.The procedure should take two parameters, the invoice id and the amount of payment. Update that record to add this payment to the total and record the payment date as today.This Is the code I'm using this code.If any other errors are seen please point them out.

```
USE AP;
IF OBJECT_ID ('spRecordPayment') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC spRecordPayment;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spRecordPayment
 @InvoiceID int,
 @PaymentAmount money
AS

BEGIN
SELECT InvoiceId,InvoiceTotal
FROM Invocies
WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceID
    IF @PaymentAmount > InvoiceTotal
        DECLARE @CreditTotal MONEY;
        SET @CreditTotal = @PaymentAmount - InvoiceTotal;

        UPDATE Invoices
        SET CreditTotal = @CreditTotal
        WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

        UPDATE Invoices
        SET PaymentDate = GETDATE()
    ELSE --This is Line 21

     DECLARE @CreditTotal2 MONEY;
     SET @CreditTotal2 = InvoiceTotal - @PaymentAmount;

     UPDATE Invoices
     SET CreditTotal = @CreditTotal2
     WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

     UPDATE Invoices
     SET PaymentDate = GETDATE()
END
```

It Gives Me This Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spRecordPayment, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: Are you going to make us guess what the error message is that you're getting?  My crystal ball is broken...

Comment: Hey sorry i noticed that i left that out @rory.ap

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that you don't have any `BEGIN...END` blocks:

```
IF (...)
    BEGIN
    ....
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    ....
    END
```

Comment: To add to this, after the `BOOLEAN` condition is checked the TSQL statement or statement grouping is executed--but if you are using a statement grouping you must use a statement block with `BEGIN` and `END`. Since you, @DanielStallard, have multiple statements in your `IF / ELSE` statement... you need to use `BEGIN / END` as Rory has stated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer i used was:

```
 USE AP;
 IF OBJECT_ID ('spRecordPayment') IS NOT NULL
 DROP PROC spSumInvoices;
 GO

CREATE PROC spRecordPayment 
@InvoiceID int,
@PaymentAmount money
AS

BEGIN
SELECT InvoiceId,InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceID
IF @PaymentAmount > (SELECT InvoiceTotal From Invoices Where InvoiceId = @InvoiceID)
Begin
        DECLARE @CreditTotal MONEY;
        SET @CreditTotal = @PaymentAmount - (SELECT InvoiceTotal From
    Invoices Where InvoiceId = @InvoiceID);

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET InvoiceTotal = 0
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET PaymentTotal = @PaymentAmount
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET CreditTotal = @CreditTotal
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET PaymentDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;
End
ELSE
Begin
 DECLARE @NewTotal MONEY;
 SET @NewTotal = (SELECT InvoiceTotal From Invoices Where
 InvoiceId            = @InvoiceID) - @PaymentAmount;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET CreditTotal = 0
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET PaymentDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    UPDATE Invoices
    SET InvoiceTotal = @NewTotal
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;
End
```